# How to differentiate between constructors

Tags: c++, pointers, templates, return-type

I have two constructors in a class template, one with array, one with vector as parameter.

I have pointer members which point to the given parameters.

I have to overload operator[] and write size() method (only one of each) that work with both but I don't know how to differentiate between the given types.

How can I tell which constructor was called?

Thanks in advance.

```
template<typename T, typename F>
class view {

const T* arrayT;
const std::vector<T>* vectT;
size_t* sizeArray;
F functor{};


view(const T array[], rsize_t sze) {
        arrayT = array; 
        sizeArray = &sze; 
    }

view(const std::vector<T> vect) {
        vectT = &vect;
    }



int size() const{
    if( ?????){
        return sizeArray;
    } else {
        return vecT-> size();
    }
}

T view<T, F>::operator[](int index) const {

     if(????) {
         functor(arrayT[index]);
     } else {
         return functor(vectT->at(index));
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a private `bool flag` at class level and set it to `true` of `false` based on the constructor being called.

The Difference can be seen easily as one them takes two parameters and the other takes only one parameter so, constructor calls can be predicted.

```
class view {
    bool flag;    
    const T* arrayT;
    const std::vector<T>* vectT;
    size_t* sizeArray;
    F functor{};

    /// Accepts two arguments
    view(const T array[], rsize_t sze) {
        flag = true;
        arrayT = array; 
        sizeArray = &sze; 
    }

    /// Accepts one argument
    view(const std::vector<T> vect) {
        flag = false;
        vectT = &vect;
    }

    int size() const {
        if (flag) {
            return sizeArray;
        } else {
            return vecT-> size();
        }
    }

    T view<T, F>::operator[](int index) const {
        if (flag) {
            functor(arrayT[index]);
        } else {
            return functor(vectT->at(index));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are doing c++17, I would advise you to have a look at **constexpr if**
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If

It is a new language feature that kinds of lets you perform **if** at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use two pointers. You can define a few more constructors, too.

```
template<typename T, typename F>
class view {
    const T* arr;
    size_t size;
    F functor;

    view(const T arr[], size_t size) : arr(arr), size(size) {}

    template <size_t N>
    view(const T (&arr)[N]) : arr(arr), size(N) {}

    view(const std::vector<T> & vec) : arr(vec.data()), size(vec.size()) {}

    template <size_t N>
    view(const std::array<T, N> & arr) : arr(arr.data()), size(N) {}

    int size() const { return size; }

    std::invoke_result_t<F, T> operator[](int index) const { return functor(arrayT[index]); }
};
```